# Optimize unranking algorithmn with duplicates

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, optimization, permutation

is it possible to optimize the given unrank with duplicates `O(n^2)` algorithm to a lower complexity level, if yes how?

The algorithm is given by this Link:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-n-th-lexicographically-permutation-string-set-2/

Comment: Where is your [attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)? Also, you'll likely get more attention if you specify your target language for answers to use in your tags.

Comment: I have no idea how to optimize the complexity. ;-(